# How to create a lookup table

Tags: c++, class, lookup-tables

Basically i've only realised that the way i've coded my project i need to implement some form of lookup table, now i have never done this before and therefore don't know how to do it and googling doesn't really give a clear set of instructions

I need the lookup table so that a user can input a function into the command line and then pass in parameters to that function, but no idea where to start

Comment: Since you're using c++, I expect there's some container type out there that you can use directly. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ probably. Short of that, you can define your own structure containing space for the lookup key, and for whatever that key is supposed to represent; create an array of this structure type, and fill the array in with its key/value mappings. Then when you read in your input, you scan the array looking for that input as a key.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "input a function into the command line". Is it a function name or a function definition?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this in order to create a lookup (dispatch) table:

(Notice: This is how to implement a dispatch table and it is both C and C++ compartible. There are other-and maybe easier ways to do this in C++ without reinventing the wheel, like using some containers etc).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Arrays start from 0.
// This is used for code
// readability reasons.
#define CASE(X) X-1 

typedef void (*chooseCase)();

// Functions to execute each case.
// Here, I am just printing
// different strings.
void case1(){
    cout<< "case1" << endl;
}

void case2(){
    cout<< "case2" << endl;
}

void case3(){
    cout<< "case3" << endl;
}

void case4(){
    cout<< "case4" << endl;
}

//Put all the cases in an array.
chooseCase cases[] = {
    case1, case2, case3, case4
};

int main()
{
    //You can call each scenario
    //by hand easily this way:
    cases[CASE(1)]();
    cout << endl;

    //Idea: You can even set in another
    // array a sequence of function executions desired.
    int casesSequence[] = {
        CASE(1), CASE(2), CASE(3), CASE(4),CASE(3),CASE(2),CASE(1)
    };
    //Execute the functions in the sequence set.
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(casesSequence)/sizeof(int)); ++i){
        cases[casesSequence[i]]();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Based on: [Adding split-screen multiplayer to c++ game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167107/adding-split-screen-multiplayer-to-c-game/18178231#18178231))

Now about the program input, you could map the name of your function to get the index for example and you could apply the example above to parameterized functions and you can also use this in situations that functions are parameterized.
In this case,please take into consideration that all functions should obey to the function pointer signature in order to use it in this example. Otherwise, you have to do more tricky things (like using a `void`* argument and passing an arguments `struct` "instance" pointer to each function).

Comment: Maybe I am getting judgemental in my old age, but as soon as I saw the macro, I believe this is a bad solution.

Comment: Macro is just for readability reasons. I am just converting the index.

Comment: The common method is to use `typedef` for declaring function types.  This avoids the evil #define macros.

Comment: define was used for readability reasons in order to sort of "convert" the index. Typedef was used to define the function pointer signature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly your requirements, but I could imagine sth like this:

You might want to have a look into [C++ function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html). You could make an own struct that holds:

1. name of a function
2. pointer to that function
3. vector of variants (for example from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) or write your[own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type)) to hold the arguments
4. validate function to see if the arguments and function pointer fit

Create for each function that the user can call a an instance of this struct. Display those to the user and let him choose. In the second step, let him enter the values for the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::map<std::string, functype>` where `functype` is a `typedef`'d function pointer, or even a `boost::function<>` type.

```
std::map<std::string, functype> funcs;

void call_user_func(const std::string &user_input, const std::string &arg1, const std::string & arg2)
{
    functype f = funcs.at(user_input);
    f(arg1, arg2);   
}
```

Comment: A caveat to `std::map` is that it must be loaded by the program at run-time.  A lookup table can be constant and static and placed in read-only memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, a `std::map` with an initializer could be `const` and `static`.  But perhaps it still couldn't be in read-only memory.

Comment: use std::unordered_map

Answer (score -1):

I give you and example on Arduino that is almost the same C/C++ code analogy

```
float cosLUT[(int) (360.0 * 1 / 0.5)] ;
const float DEG2RAD = 180 / PI ;
const float cosinePrecision = 0.5;
const int cosinePeriod = (int) (360.0 * 1 / cosinePrecision);
void setup()
{
initCosineLUT();
}
void loop()
{
// nothing for now!
}
void initCosineLUT(){
for (int i = 0 ; i < cosinePeriod ; i++)
{
cosLUT[i] = (float) cos(i * DEG2RAD * cosinePrecision);
}
}
```

Lookup tables are one of the most powerful tricks in the programming universe.
They are arrays containing precalculated values and thus replace heavy runtime
calculations by a simpler array index operation. For instance, imagine you want to
track positions of something by reading distances coming from a bunch of distance
sensors. You'll have trigonometric and probably power calculations to perform.
Because they can be time consuming for your processor, it would be smarter and
cheaper to use array content reading instead of those calculations. This is the usual
illustration for the use of lookup tables.